# Time-summing data in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to process data from a transient simulation. The data is structured as follows:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| Bin 1 | Bin 2 | Bin 3 | Bin 4 | Time Step  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| 0.1   | 0     | 0.2   | 0     | 0.1        |
| 0     | 0.3   | 0.1   | 0.5   | 0.1        |
| 0.5   | 0     | 0     | 0.2   | 0.2        |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
```

I would like it such that the data for each bin is summed in the individual time step, so for the above data, it would be:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Bin 1         Bin 2          Bin 3          Bin 4            Time step |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 0.1            0.3           0.3            0.5               0.1      |
| 0.5            0             0              0.2               0.2      |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The data is initially stored as a matrix called "data". My current approach is:

```
[h,n] = size(data);
timestep = 0.1;
timeperiod = data(h,5)-data(3,5)
%the time data is in the 5th column, the numerical data starts on the 3rd row of the table
numberofsteps = int64(timeperiod/timestep);
starttime = data(3,5);

vals_per_time=zeros(numberofsteps+1,5);
%pre-allocating a new matrix for my new restructured data

for z =1:(numberofsteps+1)
     flowtime = starttime + double(z-1)*timestep;
     %the z-1 statement is done such that the first flowtime value is the start time, but also so the 
     %equation will hold for the rest of the for loop
     vals_per_time(z,5)=flowtime;

     %populating the time column of my new matrix

  for j = 1:h
      if(data(j,5)==vals_per_time(z,5))
      %checking for if the time values in my data matrix match the current time step in my new matrix 
           for i = 1:4
                 vals_per_time(z,i) = vals_per_time(z,i) + data(j,i);
                 %there's going to be multiple entries in my data matrix that match the time step in the 
                  new matrix, and so I loop over the 4 bins and add the contributions from each entry
           end
       end
  end

end
```

For the most part, this approach works; however, for random time steps, the if statement

```
if(data(j,5)==vals_per_time(z,5))
```

doesn't work, and the vals_per_time matrix will be completely empty for that time step.

If I plot the results for one bin over time, I get something like this[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5PB9.jpg), where basically the time steps for the vals_per_time matrix aren't populated in regular intervals.

I feel like it may be due to converting values between integers and decimals in the for loop, causing certain time steps to not match in the data and vals_per_time matrix.

Please let me know if anyone has faced similar problems/has suggestions for better ways to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `varfun` for this, which will use some aggregation function (`sum` in this case) to summarise your table:

```
% Create the data table
Bin1 = [0.1, 0, 0.5].';
Bin2 = [0, 0.3, 0].';
Bin3 = [0.2, 0.1, 0].';
Bin4 = [0, 0.5, 0.2].';
TimeStep = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2].';
tbl = table(Bin1,Bin2,Bin3,Bin4,TimeStep);
% Aggregate
tbl = varfun( @sum, tbl, 'GroupingVariables', 'TimeStep' );
% Remove automatically created column
tbl.GroupCount = [];
```

Output:

[image: table]

You can create a table from your matrix using `array2table`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`groupsummary`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.groupsummary.html) function will take care of this for you, using the `sum` computation method.

```
    [sums, flowtimes] = groupsummary(data(:,1:end-1), data(:,end), 'sum');
    vals_per_time = [sums flowtimes]; % Assembles the output as per the example (if required)
```

The function also has intuitive behaviour for `table` inputs if you choose to construct one instead of (or from) a matrix for legibility.

Comment: Worth noting this was only introduced in R2018a